# Creating table rows for measurements in forms

Tags: qgis, table, forms

I have a question about forms combined with tables.

I'm trying to create a form which allows me to add multiple rows of data to a point e.g.

[image]

I want be able to create multiple rows and fill these in in the same form as the other part of the survey.
This is needed because a single object can have the need for multiple measurements.

Below the survey i want to add this function too.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I hope you can help me out, this would make inspection work which require measurements of multiple object from a single installation simpler.

Comment: Are you asking how to expand/modify your current form?